# How to concat JSON field into another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, html-table

Here is the data in question:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "owner": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/3/",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredient": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "category": "Fruit",
                    "name": "Apple",
                    "calories": 100.0,
                },
                "numOf": 4
            },
            {
                "ingredient": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "category": "Vegetable",
                    "name": "Potato",
                    "calories": 10.0,
                },
                "numOf": 3
            }
        ],
        "total_number": 0
    }
]
```

I want to concate `numOf` into hist parent `ingredient` for my table to render properly Right now given 2 ingredients my table has 4 rows

**Edit**

Desired result should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "owner": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/3/",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredient": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "category": "Fruit",
                    "name": "Apple",
                    "calories": 100.0,
                    "numOf": 4,
                }
            },
            {
                "ingredient": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "category": "Vegetable",
                    "name": "Potato",
                    "calories": 10.0,
                    "numOf": 3,
                }
            }
        ],
        "total_number": 0
    }
]
```

The JSON file you see is my server response when queried about user's fridge. Then I want to dispaly all of his ingredient's in a table.
Here's how I declare the array in VueJS:

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'Fridge',
    data() {
        return {
            username: '',
            fridge: {},
            ingredients: []
        }
    },
}
```

Here's the code that loops through response data and adds `ingredients` object and store's it in array called `ingredients`. I've tried declaring is a object but it didn't work.

```
for (let i = 0; i < res.data["ingredients"].length; i++) {
 var obj = this.fridge.ingredients[i]
 for (var key in obj) {
  var value = obj[key]
  this.ingredients.push(value)
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us the desired result? The description itself is not clear enough yet. What have you tried yourself so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through each item in the ingredient `key` of each item in the array of data and for each item add the `numOf` key in the `ingredient` object and remove the `numOf` on the parent item.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "owner": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/3/",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredient": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "category": "Fruit",
                    "name": "Apple",
                    "calories": 100.0,
                },
                "numOf": 4
            },
            {
                "ingredient": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "category": "Vegetable",
                    "name": "Potato",
                    "calories": 10.0,
                },
                "numOf": 3
            }
        ],
        "total_number": 0
    }
];

data[0].ingredients.map((item, index) => {
  item["ingredient"]["numOf"] = item["numOf"];
  delete item["numOf"];
});

console.log(data);
```

If you want to be more dynamic and not be specific as in the previous code

you can procide like this

```
data.forEach(dataItem => {
  dataItem.ingredients.map((item, index) => {
    item["ingredient"]["numOf"] = item["numOf"];
    delete item["numOf"];
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using a map and returning inside of the map when it's not being assigned to anything? A forEach would be better here.

Comment: Of course that isn't needed, I just convert `Array.prototype.reduce` to `Array.prototype.map` did not remove the return key

Comment: Your last example is also using a `forEach` and a `map`.  A `map` is used to return data from the function, but if you aren't needing anything returned, a `forEach` would be better.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 loops to iterate over the data, adding the `numOf` to the ingredient and then deleting it.

The first loop will loop over all items in `data`, the second loops over all `ingredients` in that object.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "owner": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/3/",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredient": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "category": "Fruit",
                    "name": "Apple",
                    "calories": 100.0,
                },
                "numOf": 4
            },
            {
                "ingredient": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "category": "Vegetable",
                    "name": "Potato",
                    "calories": 10.0,
                },
                "numOf": 3
            }
        ],
        "total_number": 0
    }
]

data.forEach((d) => {
  d.ingredients.forEach((i) => {
    i.ingredient.numOf = i.numOf
    delete i.numOf
  })
})

console.log(data)
```